# Android: onListItemClick not getting called in ListActivity

Tags: android, onclick, listactivity

I'm having problems with my first Android app.

I have subclassed ListActivity, and I'm having no luck getting the overridden onListItemClick() to respond to click events. I've read focus can be a problem, but changing focus in the XML files does not seem to work. Here's the relevant bits of code. Anyone see what's I've buggered up?

```
public class Notepadv1 extends ListActivity {
    private int mNoteNumber = 1;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
    }

 private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };


    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    String message = "row clicked!";
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.show();

}
```

notepad_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:dividerHeight="6dp"/>



  <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_notes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And notes_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a ListActivity, used your onListItemClick, and notes_row.xml. The code works for me. However, I believe you are expecting the *entire row* to respond to a click, according to notes_row you need to click on the *text* itself (not anywhere in the row).

Try changing the width attribute in notes_row.xml to `"match_parent"`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Now the entire row responds to user clicks.

Comment: Haha! Thanks so much. What a plonker I am. Clicking on the text works fine now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution in case this helps anyone:  I had a Button in each of my list items, and this prevented my onListItemClick event from firing.  Replacing the Button with a TextView that looked exactly the same made it work.

Comment: FYI: This occurs not only with buttons but with TextViews that have a `background` set. I used `focusable="false"` to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Implements OnItemClickListener and do list.setOnItemClickListener.

```
public class Notepadv1 extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener { 

   onCreate() 
   {
        ....

       ((ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setOnItemClickListener(this)

    }

}
```

Comment: The author is extending a ListActivity, overriding [onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) is the better approach since it is already implemented.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it didn't work, I'm afraid. However just before I tried that, I got the dialog popping up showing success after the phone display had gone off for a while. Can't repeat it though.