# onListItemClick never called when using tab navigation

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListActivity` which displays a ladder of ranked players in a sports club. The navigation mode is set to tabs. When I try to implement `onListItemClick` it never gets called. I read through a lot of other posts like [Android: onListItemClick not getting called in ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369382/android-onlistitemclick-not-getting-called-in-listactivity) and [onListItemClick is not getting called on ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373527/onlistitemclick-is-not-getting-called-on-listactivity) where people recommended setting the widgets in the list to `android:focusable="false"`, however this does not seem to be working out for me. I don't know if the tabs navigation has anything to do with this, but anyway- below is my code.

**Activity's onCreate to onListItemClick**

```
public class Rankings extends ListActivity
{

    ArrayList<Club> clubs;
    public static ArrayList<RankedPlayer> Women = new ArrayList<RankedPlayer>();
    public static ArrayList<RankedPlayer> Men = new ArrayList<RankedPlayer>();
    int menuPosition = 0;
    private static Context context;
    public static TabSelected _tab;
    RankingEditorMode mode;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rankings);

        clubs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("clubs");

        context = Rankings.this;

        final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab men = actionbar.newTab();
        men.setText("Men");
        men.setIcon(R.drawable.signs_man_32x32);
        men.setTabListener(new TabListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
            {
                _tab = TabSelected.Men;
                GoToFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        Tab women = actionbar.newTab();
        women.setText("Women");
        women.setIcon(R.drawable.signs_woman_32x32);
        women.setTabListener(new TabListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
            {
                _tab = TabSelected.Women;
                GoToFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        actionbar.addTab(men);
        actionbar.addTab(women);


        GetRankings();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

        System.out.println("\n\n\n>>>>>>>>>>   Popup <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\n\n");

        AlertDialog.Builder popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(Rankings.this);
        popup.setCancelable(true);
        popup.setTitle("Share Log?");

        String message = clubs.get(menuPosition).getName();
        if(_tab == TabSelected.Men)
        {
            message += "\t-\t Men";
        }
        else
        {
            message += "\t-\t Women";
        }
        popup.setMessage(message);

        popup.setPositiveButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                ShareLog();
            }
        });

        popup.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ranking_fragment extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
        ArrayList<RankedPlayer> rankings;
        if(Rankings._tab == TabSelected.Men)
        {
            rankings = Rankings.Men;
        }
        else
        {
            rankings = Rankings.Women;
        }

        RankingAdapter adapter = new RankingAdapter(getActivity(), rankings);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class RankingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RankedPlayer>
{

      private final Context context;
      ArrayList<RankedPlayer> rankings;

    public RankingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RankedPlayer> rankings) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.jarvis_log, rankings);
        this.context = context;
        this.rankings = rankings;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ranking_layout, parent, false);

        TextView rank = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvRanking_rank);
        TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvRanking_name);
        TextView club = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvRanking_club);
        TextView points = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvRanking_points);

        rank.setText((position+1)+".");
        name.setText("\t"+rankings.get(position).getName());
        points.setText(rankings.get(position).getPoints()+"\t");

        if(rankings.get(position).getClub().length() >= 1)
        {
            club.setText("\t("+rankings.get(position).getClub()+")");
        }
        else
        {
            club.setText("");
        }
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**Activity's Layout xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="rankings.Rankings"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**ranking_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/OrangeRed"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRanking_rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="1."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRanking_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvRanking_rank"
        android:text="Steve Coppinger"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRanking_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="900"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRanking_club"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvRanking_name"
        android:text=" (KZN)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual lists are not in the activity, but in the fragments. Therefor `onListItemClick` in the `Activity` is never called. You have to implement it in the `Fragment` class. Your `Activity` also doesn't has to be a `ListActivity`.

Comment: Perfect answer. Just fiddling around with some stuff but will post the working solution as an extra answer once I'm done. Thanx a lot @MatF

Answer (score 0):

There is no declaration of fragment in your main activity, that's why it it not even visible to the activity. You simply make an activity and listview must be loaded in main activity, just call adapter through fragment.